# Local DynamoDB: Unable to execute HTTP request — Connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I run local DynamoDB and an app via `docker-compose`. Unfortunately I encounter an error when querying DynamoDB from the app:

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb:80 [dynamodb/172.18.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Here is how the docker-compose looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  dynamodb:
    image: "dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: app-dynamodb
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
  api:
    image: "app-backend:latest"
    container_name: app-api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5100:5100"
    environment:
      - DYNAMO_HOST=dynamodb:80
```

Here is how a Dockerfile for DynamoDB:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ENV DYNAMODB_VERSION=latest

COPY .aws/ root/.aws/
COPY setup.sh setup.sh
COPY setup-stats.sh setup-stats.sh

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python python-pip && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install awscli && \
    apt-get clean all && \
    curl -O https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    rm dynamodb_local_${DYNAMODB_VERSION}.tar.gz

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT java -Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar --sharedDb -inMemory
```

**UPDATE:**

1. I'm able to connect to dynamoDB JS shell from the host by http://localhost/shell
2. I'm NOT able to connect to dynamoDB from the app container:

```
wget dynamodb/shell
Connecting to dynamodb (172.18.0.2:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.18.0.2): Connection refused
```

3. The app is written on Scala and uses Scanamo for interaction with DynamoDB

Comment: did you try to connect to dynamo on port 8000?. I'm not sure that you be able to connect to dynamo on port 80 from a container in the same network, because the port 80 is to expose the service to the external network (that's the reason that you are able to connect from the host machine). Instead of this, try to change the `DYNAMO_HOST` env variable to `dynamodb:8000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in missed `DYNAMO_ACCESS_KEY` and `DYNAMO_SECRET_KEY`
Despite the dyanmoDB is local and runs in-memory, it requires `access_key` and `secret_key` values any way

Furthermore, these values should NOT be empty! So set there anything you want, like "foo" or "bar".

Answer (score 2):

I can see that there is no communication between the DB and the API container. There is a Docker **Links** Key-Value pair which will help. Please find the updated docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  dynamodb:
    image: "dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: app-dynamodb
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
  api:
    image: "app-backend:latest"
    container_name: app-api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5100:5100"
    links:
      - dynamodb
    environment:
      - DYNAMO_HOST=dynamodb:80
```

This may be the solution Please let me know the Status.

Comment: My problem was solved by the comment, I posted above ;)